# JSON value '{assetid ="xx"; fileName = "IMG_8189.PNG"; uri = "file:///var/mobile/cpntainers/Application/"} of type NSMutableDictionary != Valid url

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-storage

I’m using Expo to write React Native app and trying to save the image to the Firebase storage. Upload is successful but this error breaks me out from the Expo. Could someone advise the solution, please? Thanks.

JSON value '{assetid ="xx"; fileName = "IMG_8189.PNG"; uri = "file:///var/mobile/cpntainers/Application/"} of type NSMutableDictionary cannot be converted to a valid URL.

```js
const pickImageAsync = async () => {
  const image = await ImagePickerTool.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    allowsEditing: false,
    quality: 1,
  });

  if (!image.cancelled) {
    setImportedImage(image);
  } else {
    alert("You did not select any image.");
    return;
  }

  setPickedImage(image);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(image.uri);
    console.log("mdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", image.uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    const storageRef = ref(storage, `profiles/${image.name}`); // specify profiles folder
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blob);

    // wait for upload to complete
    await uploadTask;

    console.log("Image uploaded to Firebase Storage");

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading image to Firebase Storage:", error);
  }
};
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I have fixed the formatting in your code. Please double-check your post after you create it to ensure that the markdown is properly formatted and your code samples are complete. Your post title should be changed to state the *specific error message*. Titles that reference "this error" or "an error" are generic and useless titles; make your title stand out by referencing your *specific* problem.